# How do I estimate VECM with weak exogeneity restrictions placed in R?

Tags: r, vector-error-correction-model

I am estimating a VECM model.  I would like to impose weak exogeneity restricitions on the estimation of VECM in R.  How do I implement this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check the `urca` package

Comment: See Pfaff "Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R" Chapter 8, too. I am not sure if there is a function for restricted estimation of VECM in packages `urca` or `vars`. (Although there certainly are functions for testing restrictions on the loadings matrix $\alpha$ and the cointegration vectors' matrix $\beta$, like `alrtest`, `blrtest`, `ablrtest` in `urca`). However, once you have cointegrating vectors produced by function `ca.jo` in `urca` and have determined the lag order, you can run the estimation by OLS where you construct the right-hand side variables manually.

Answer (score 1):

Weak exogeneity means that
$$
\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
What you need to do is to estimate the cointegrating relations ($\beta$) under this restriction, and then you can just use usual techniques conditional on this.

Have a look at Estimation and Hypothesis Testing of Cointegration Vectors in Gaussian Vector Autoregressive Models, Søren Johansen, Econometrica, Vol. 59, No. 6 (Nov., 1991) , pp. 1551-1580 and Theorem 3.1, which describes ML estimation under $\alpha=A\psi$, which is what you have (with $A=(I, 0)'$).